# How does a Turing machine simulate itself

Tags: turing-machines

I have a problem regarding Recursion Theorem in Computation Theory.
So Turing machines can have themselves as input. So they can simulate themselves(this technique have been used in many proofs i saw).
what does a Turing machine that only simulates itself does?(assume the machine has only 2 commands get it's description and simulate it, so it looks like it falls into a loop and simulates forever) does it ever halt? if it does what is its output
I tried to ask around and some said this machine functions as an identity machine and does nothing. (because in the other case it brings down so many problems on the theory)
so I asked another question assume Turing machine T with input x. all this machine does is that it simulates itself on x+1.
the concept of Recursion Theorem is very vague in my mind and I will be thankful if you help me find it's deeper meaning.
p.s : I will be grateful if you recommend me any paper or article about similar concepts in other theories so I understand it better

Comment: Remember that Turing Machines are equivalent to Partial Functions, hence you can think of TM as a (partial or total) function from N to N. Since TM are countable you can enumerate them. Once the enumeration is fixed, you can think of passing a TM as input to another (or possibly itself). That doesn't mean that the machine passed will be simulated, it depends only on what the machine you are passing to does. What you are probably referring to is the Universal Turing Machine which indeed on input n simulates the nth machine. In that case, if you pass a UTM to itself will just act as a UTM.

Comment: This looks like an answer.

Comment: Of course it will never halt. What is your question?

Comment: tnx, I guess I didn't Understand the concept of simulation correctly and took the blame on the recursion theorem. sorry I'm still noob in the concept